# org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I am connecting MySQL database with my SQLite and Android. I got JSON object error. It throws me the org.json.Exception.

```
     try
    { 
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        name=(json_data.getString("name"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name : "+name,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you get an xml stream instead of json Can you show the result and the full stacktrace please?

Comment: pardon me but i laughed out big loud when i saw JSONException and <?XML together in the question headline. :)

Comment: Have you searched for the error message you are getting?

Comment: Yes i have searched for the error

Answer (score 1):

Look at *result* string, It is not JSON but XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is in XML formt,In your server side use `json_encode(data)`

Comment: <?php
 $host='127.0.0.1';
 $uname='root';
 $pwd='';
 $db="android";

 $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
 mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
  
 $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
  
 $r=mysql_query("select * from sample where id='$id'",$con);

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
 {
  $flag[name]=$row[name];
 }
  
 print(json_encode($flag));
 mysql_close($con);
?>